# Webhook Call failed, intent is called up 2 times

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Currently, I am facing major 2 problems with dialogflow.

I am building a chatbot for insurance domain.

1. Webhoook call failed

Currently, I am using a free version of it. So, the first problem is sometimes webhook call failed for the particular intent. It is happening sometimes. Is this issue due to free version?

Error in firebase(free version) -:

dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsDailyNonbillable' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-1d'

2. Intent is calling up 2 times

I have created several intents with follow-up intents, means one intent is followed up by another intent.

So, I have one intent called "XYZ" and which is asking for entering zip code. Then, if I enter zip code and then it is prompting that you have entered zip code: ... and asking for US address. So, if I enter US address which may contain number and alphabets, then it is again going on the same intent of zip code saying okay, your zip code is ... and asking for US address.

Similar thing happen for some other intent too.

I have tried changing lifespans and also disable some functions with that intent in webhook as well.

Getting outputs like -:

[image]

And if I enter address (137 Teaticket Hwy) then It will be prompted again like shown below

[image]

Any suggestions why is it repeating 2 times. What could be the possible reasons for it?

Further If I again enter address, it moves to next intent like shown below -:

[image]

Screenshots for intent is as follows -:

[image]

More training examples for city-state intent
[image]

Responses for City-State intent
[image]

Address Intent
[image]
Response for address intent
[image]

Comment: For your second part, can you update the question to include screen shots of the Intent you're using to get the zip code, and the Intent you're using to get the rest of the address?

Comment: I have added more screenshots. this thing happens sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: Again, can you show the Intent itself, not the test console. Seeing how the training phrases, Input Context, and Output Context are important.

Comment: Sure, let me do that.

Comment: I have added some more screenshots of intent.

Comment: I think the problem is it is not able to identify the parameter and assigning wrong intent. But how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is that your "city-state" Intent, where you expect the user to enter the zip code, is valid whenever the "zip-followup" context is active. Since it is active for at least 2 rounds, that means that the next time through, it may still consider the "city-state" Intent as a possible valid Intent to match, and then match it.

You can try setting the "zip-followup" Context to a lifespan of 0, which will clear it out, as part of the Outgoing Contexts for the "city-state" Intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this thing has solved my problem for now.